# Does the termination point(level) influence water flow from a pipe

Tags: water, home-experiment, flow

I get water to my home from a nearby Tank A at a certain height above ground level.
I have a 1" pipe through which I get this water to my home.. I leave this water into my well by connecting a 1" tube to this pipe.

Reason for question: I have seen water pressure vary(lower- more flow) depending upon the height I hold my pipe(on the outlet side) when I empty my fish tank, keeping how deep the pipe is immersed on the other side a constant.

Now, if I elongate and leave the pipe from Tank A at deeper level below ground level should the flow rate increase?(will i get more water in the same time) as apposed to a shorter pipe which still goes into my well.

or simply:
Will I empty my overhead tank on 2nd floor quicker if I use the tap on the ground floor instead of the tap on the second floor. The taps being same size.

Comment: can you not use both taps at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

A longer (and deeper emerged pipe) will yield a slightly lower flow rate. This is because the longer pipe will yield a higher drop in the loss of pressure, due to friction. A longer and deeper pipe will never increase the flowrate, since what is causing the water to flow is the height difference between the two water surfaces (assuming both are subjected to atmospheric pressure).

For more information lookup Bernoulli's principle:
$$
p_1+\frac{1}{2}{\rho}v_1^2+{\rho}gz_1=p_2+\frac{1}{2}{\rho}v_2^2+{\rho}gz_2+\left(f\frac{L}{D}+{\sum}K\right)\frac{1}{2}{\rho}v_2^2
$$

Comment: I agree with friction coming into play with longer pipes. I just added this to question: Will I empty my overhead tank on 2nd floor quicker if I use the tap on the ground floor instead of the tap on the second floor. The taps being same size.

Comment: This depends on what kind of pipe setup is used, since even though the pressure difference when there is no flow is greater, I can't say what the pressure drop would be as an function of the flowspeed.